# Api running async method in the background without the use of a button?

Tags: c#, httprequest

Okay, so I have this API that I want to load in the background of my app the second it starts up I do initialize the request. But I do not call the async task anywhere and I do not want to use a button for this. I have my own Class that will take the data that comes from the response but I just want it to be handed over to another method so I can use it there and not have to show the data to the user. How should I go about this? this is my code from both Mainwindow.xaml.cs and API.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;



namespace TestAPi
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Api.InitializeClient(""); 



        }


    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers; 
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http; 


namespace TestAPi
{
    public class Api
    {
        private static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set;}
        private string url { get; set;}

        public static void InitializeClient(string token)
        {       
            ApiClient = new HttpClient();
            ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("your url");
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear(); 
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Bearer Authentication")); 
        }


        public async Task<Data> LoadData()
        {
            url = ApiClient.BaseAddress.ToString();
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Data data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<data>();

                    return data; 
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);

                }


            }  
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: just pass a function to the load data so i can be called once the data is loaded or provide an event...

Comment: if you make it public is it just calling it in the main then or would that step on some foots and be a bad way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your viewmodel, create a command that calls the method and uses the result

```
public AsyncCommand LoadCommand { get; }

// in constructor
LoadCommand = new AsyncCommand(LoadAndUse);
```

In XAML, hook the command to the Loaded event of the window

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: You need a seperate library for this?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it helps to keep things clean - you could use an event handler directly, but that doesn't play well with MVVM

Comment: so what would that seperate library be?

Comment: Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding your goal. I thought you wanted to show the data in the window after they're loaded (why else use the API client in there?). But after another reading of your question I'm not so sure. Where do you want to use the data after you (asynchronously) load it?

Comment: im gonna spit it in to another database!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the async producer consumer design pattern could be useful in your use case scenario, and to support that you can consider the usage of Channels available on dotnet core framework. 
Your producer would be the Class that would do the http request, and after that it should post the response in the a channel so the consumer class takes that data and do whatever it needs to do with that. 
Here is a [simple example](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels) to understand the concepts arround Producer Consumer and Channels.